# How do i net Core Console catching the error

Tags: .net

I need one console application. In the html page column in the file ending in .csv, it will find src and get the link in src. It will then make a request on this link. If there is an error, it will print 404 next to the link. it will write the status code if the link is working. Then it will give me this as an output in the txt file. How can I do that ? Is there anyone who can help?

A few blocks of code I wrote :

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using StreamWriter = System.IO.StreamWriter;

namespace Csv.Status
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string corrupted;
        private static string modify;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
            corrupted = appSettings["Status"];
            modify = appSettings["Modify"];

            DirectoryInfo startDir = new DirectoryInfo(corrupted);

            RecurseFileStructure recurseFileStructure = new RecurseFileStructure();
            recurseFileStructure.TraverseDirectory(startDir);
        }

        public class RecurseFileStructure
        {
            public void TraverseDirectory(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
            {
                var subdirectories = directoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories();

                foreach (var subdirectory in subdirectories)
                {
                    TraverseDirectory(subdirectory);
                }

                var files = directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles();
                int counter = 0;
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (file.Name.EndsWith(".csv"))
                    {
                        counter += 1;
                        var percentage = (counter * 100) / files.Count();
                        HandleFile(file);
                        Console.WriteLine("%" + percentage + " of files is done.");
                    }
                }
            }

            void HandleFile(FileInfo file)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", file.Name);
                try
                {
                    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(corrupted + file.Name);
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(modify + file.Name))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Process has started...");
                        for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)
                        {
                            if (lines[i].Contains("src="))
                            {
                                var percentage = (i * 100) / lines.Count();
                                Console.WriteLine(i + "th line was corrupted at %" + percentage + " and recovered.");
                                // işlemler burada gerçekleşecek. 
                                lines[i] = lines[i].
                            }
                            writer.WriteLine(lines[i]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Fully healed.");
                        writer.Flush();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow the question: how can you do what - complete your requirements? What's wrong with the code you've written, what specifically do you need help with? Just moving the try-catch to somewhere where you can recover from it? What errors does it catch, the 404?

Comment: @Rup Hi sir. Example src="https://www.link.com" . This page has 404 status. 

`var percentage = (i * 100) / lines.Count();
                                Console.WriteLine(i + "th line was corrupted at %" + percentage + " and recovered.");
                                // işlemler burada gerçekleşecek. 
                                lines[i] = lines[i].`


Within this code, the 404 page will be captured and it will give me the 404 status or other statuses as output.